# What is the meaning of "Ce ne sont que de"? Why is there an inversion in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, inversion

> « **Ce ne sont que de** simples soldats, mais on s'entendait bien. »

I suppose that the entire sentence means something along the lines of:

> "They’re just some simple soldiers, but we got along well."

However, I’m not sure how to interpret the "**Ce ne sont que de**" part. I suppose that "**de**" and "**ne ... que**" mean "**some**" and "**only**" respectively, but I’m at a loss as to the inversion "**ce ... sont**".

Comment: “Sont ne ce que …” would be gibberish. I don't understand where you're seeing an inversion here, what word order were you expecting?

Comment: Seconding that. *Ce* = pronoun for almost anything depending on context; *sont* = *are*. So *ce sont* = *they are.* Why would you expect it to be inverted? By the way you're correct about *de* and *ne...que*, although really in English you would leave out *some* -- it's just "They're not but simple soldiers." A particle like *de* is required in French where in English we would have nothing.

Comment: @Gilles how would you form the interrogative of a sentence with *ce sont* though? I don't think I've ever seen *Sont-ce...* I mean aside from using *est-ce que* or just phrasing it as a declarative.

Comment: Est-ce sont? That's a new one.

Comment: @Vérace Neither sentence is correct French.

Comment: @Aerovistae “[Sont-ce](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sont-ce%22)” is correct.

Comment: Why did he add *maman*, I have to wonder

Comment: Est-ce que ce sont? Ça ne marche pas? J'ai ajouté "maman" pour en faire une question.

Comment: (Est-ce que ce sont is not what you wrote above)

Comment: @Aerovistae When you wrote that _not_ in "they're not but simple soldiers", did you mean _nought_ or _nothing_? It is not on topic but I think the _not_ should drop altogether imho but I wonder why you presented it like that?

Comment: It's a valid phrasing. It's old fashioned but equivalent to "only" or "just." I sometimes use it when translating *ne...que* just because it's a more literal translation and can help people see the equivalency in meaning.

Comment: @Aerovistae J'ai relu et j'ai barré - quelle faute <Doh...>

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Maybe "they are naught but simple soldiers"? "Nought" is more like zero or null. Just checked though, nought is an acceptable North American variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no inversion.**

**Meaning of *Ce ne sont que de* :**

Affirmative:

> **C'est** (une pomme, ...) , **Ce sont** (des pommes) =>  **It is** ...

Negative: *ne pas*

> Ce **ne** sont **pas** (des pommes) =>  It is **not** ...

Restrictive: *ne que*

> Ce **ne** sont **que** (des pommes) =>  It is **only / just** ...

Partitive:

> Les soldats => **Des** soldats => **Des** soldats simples => **Des** simples
>   soldats => **De** simples soldats.

Comment: C'est=This is, Ce sont=These are, Ce ne sont pas=These are not, Ce ne sont que=These are only applies

Answer (score 2):

n'être + que = to only be, ce ne sont que des simple soldats

These are just simple soldiers. It is the same as: Ils ne sont que des simples soldats

Ce sont des [whatever plural noun] or C'est [whatever singular noun] is made into a question by writing: Est-ce que ce sont des simples soldats? or Sont-ils des simples soldats. In the singular: C'est un soldat for a question becomes Est-ce un soldat? or Est-ce que c'est un soldat or Est-il (un) soldat.

To sum this up: Ce sont [these are] or C'est [this is] become questions by adding /Est-ce que c'est/ une pomme? (singular) or /Est-ce que ce sont/des pommes? (plural) or by inverting the verb être without the /ce/: Sont-elles des pommes and Est-elle une pomme? Though be careful: Est-elle une pomme can also mean: Is she an apple.....which is why: Est-ce que c'est une pomme is preferable....though: Est-il (un) soldat and Sont-ils des soldats can only mean Is he/are they soldiers....